# Align text to the right side in people picker in spfx react

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, peoplepicker, spfx-extension

I need to show selected user in the end(Right side) of the people picker in spfx react. is there any css or property available for that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding more context like your code so we can help you better as there's a lot of different css rules that work in specific contexts.

Here's a couple css rules that could maybe help you:

-text-align: right
-right: 0px
-float: right
-margin-left: auto